# Vector blur aliasing fix?

Tags: compositing-nodes, antialiasing

I have an animation with some characters moving at a relatively decent speed. I am using the Vector Blur node (and a vector pass, of course) to add motion blur to the renders. I am using an HDRi as a sky/light source. Unfortunately, when the moving objects move in front of the sky, strange aliasing issues seem to appear that are not as present elsewhere.

Could somebody please direct me to a method to reduce this unfortunate artifact?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some inages to demonstrate the artifacts you’re experiencing.

Comment: I guess it is coming from Z-depth socket of VB node. If so, then you can re-render scene in 2x or 4x resolution with material override in order to get Z-depth a bit smoother (after scaling down)